# Copy the text to the field when click on the button

Tags: jquery

On the page, the H2 header with its id, the button with its id, and the hidden field with its id. It is necessary to copy the contents of the H2 header to the hidden field when clicking on the button. A second click on the button clears the field and adds the title again.

I try this and other options, but I do something wrong.

```php
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('#button_id').click(function() {
                jQuery('h2').change('#field_id').val();
            });
        });
```

```js
 jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#button_id').click(function() {
   jQuery('h2').change('#field_id').val();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Some text</h2>

<input type="text" name="article" value="" id="field_id">

<a href="#" id="button_id">Link</a>
```

Comment: Please add html code also, or create a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Amit please ask to create a [runnable stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of a jsfiddle - if the code is off site, then the question is off topic for SO

Comment: @layiro Welcome to SO, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: @Amit I added a sample code, look, please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to get the field element and by calling .val() function give innerHTML of h2 element to it?

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#button_id').click(function() {
        jQuery('#field_id').val(jQuery('h2').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the right direction, I think, but it does not work)

Comment: @layiro I have edited my answer, seems that .html() function does the trick